# border-only ghost window blocking mouse clicks

Tags: debian, x11, xfce, mouse, display-manager

At some point (I don't remember when it started), some kind of ghost window appeared that only has a border (displays as rounded but behaves as rectangular), blocks mouse clicks, and won't disappear when I minimize all windows.

What might this be, what might have caused this, and most importantly, how might I be able to get rid of this?

Here is some additional information that might help diagnose the issue:

- This does not seem to affect the lock screen.
- The behavior with the Alt-Tab window switcher is very strange when I click on a window:

  - If the I click outside the ghost window, it immediately switches to the window I clicked on.
  - If the I click inside the ghost window, it immediately closes the window switcher, but doesn't open the new window until I move my mouse outside the ghost window. The final position of my mouse doesn't seem to matter.
- I'm using Xfce version 4.18 with GTK version 3.24.37, as part of Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm).
- I have xserver-xorg version 1:7.7+23 and xserver-xorg-core version 2:21.1.7-3.
- The panel at the top of my screen doesn't respond to mouse clicks, but the data it displays does update, and the apps menu works when I activate it with a keyboard shortcut.
- Here is the output of `xwininfo -d :0 -all` after clicking on the ghost window:

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x1b75612 "xfce4-panel"

  Root window id: 0x6d1 (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x6d1 (the root window) (has no name)
     1 child:
     0x1b75613 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +2926+461

  Absolute upper-left X:  2927
  Absolute upper-left Y:  462
  Relative upper-left X:  2927
  Relative upper-left Y:  462
  Width: 328
  Height: 637
  Depth: 32
  Visual: 0x6ba
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x1a00002 (not installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: yes
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: yes
  Corners:  +2927+462  -585+462  -585-341  +2927-341
  -geometry 328x637+2927+462

  Bit gravity: NorthWestGravity
  Window gravity: NorthWestGravity
  Backing-store hint: NotUseful
  Backing-planes to be preserved: 0xffffffff
  Backing pixel: 0
  Save-unders: Yes

  Someone wants these events:
      KeyPress
      KeyRelease
      ButtonPress
      ButtonRelease
      EnterWindow
      LeaveWindow
      PointerMotion
      ButtonMotion
      Exposure
      VisibilityChange
      StructureNotify
      FocusChange
      PropertyChange
  Do not propagate these events:
  Override redirection?: Yes

  Window manager hints:
      Client accepts input or input focus: Yes
      Initial state is Normal State
      Window type:
          Popup Menu
      Process id: 2661 on host <redacted>

  Normal window size hints:
      Program supplied minimum size: 328 by 637
      Program supplied maximum size: 328 by 637
      Program supplied base size: 0 by 0
      Program supplied window gravity: NorthWestGravity
  No zoom window size hints defined

  No window shape defined
  No border shape defined
```

- Here is the output of `xwininfo -d :0 -all` after clicking on the panel at the top of the screen:

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x1a00003 "xfce4-panel"

  Root window id: 0x6d1 (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x1200587 (has no name)
     4 children:
     0x1a0000e (has no name): ()  90x50+1190+0  +3750+416
        1 child:
        0x2800003 "wrapper-2.0": ("wrapper-2.0" "Wrapper-2.0")  90x50+0+0  +3750+416
           1 child:
           0x2800004 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +3749+415
     0x1a0000d (has no name): ()  69x50+1121+0  +3681+416
        1 child:
        0x2600003 "wrapper-2.0": ("wrapper-2.0" "Wrapper-2.0")  69x50+0+0  +3681+416
           4 children:
           0x2600029 (has no name): ()  22x22+24+1  +3705+417
              1 child:
              0x1c00003 "xfce4-power-manager": ("xfce4-power-manager" "Xfce4-power-manager")  22x22+0+0  +3705+417
                 1 child:
                 0x1c00004 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +3704+416
           0x2600019 (has no name): ()  22x22+0+26  +3681+442
              1 child:
              0x3000003 "Ethernet network connection “Wired connection 1” active": ("nm-applet" "Nm-applet")  22x22+0+0  +3681+442
                 1 child:
                 0x3000004 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +3680+441
           0x260000a (has no name): ()  22x22+0+1  +3681+417
              1 child:
              0xc00010 "IBus Panel": ("ibus-ui-gtk" "ibus-ui-gtk")  22x22+0+0  +3681+417
                 1 child:
                 0xc00011 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +3680+416
           0x2600004 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +3680+415
     0x1a0000c (has no name): ()  254x50+695+0  +3255+416
        1 child:
        0x2400003 "wrapper-2.0": ("wrapper-2.0" "Wrapper-2.0")  254x50+0+0  +3255+416
           1 child:
           0x2400004 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +3254+415
     0x1a00004 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +2559+415

  Absolute upper-left X:  2560
  Absolute upper-left Y:  416
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 1280
  Height: 51
  Depth: 32
  Visual: 0x6ba
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x1a00002 (not installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +2560+416  -0+416  -0-973  +2560-973
  -geometry 1280x51-0+416

  Bit gravity: NorthWestGravity
  Window gravity: NorthWestGravity
  Backing-store hint: NotUseful
  Backing-planes to be preserved: 0xffffffff
  Backing pixel: 0
  Save-unders: No

  Someone wants these events:
      KeyPress
      KeyRelease
      ButtonPress
      ButtonRelease
      EnterWindow
      LeaveWindow
      PointerMotion
      ButtonMotion
      Exposure
      VisibilityChange
      StructureNotify
      FocusChange
      PropertyChange
  Do not propagate these events:
  Override redirection?: No

  Window manager hints:
      Client accepts input or input focus: Yes
      Initial state is Normal State
      Displayed on all desktops
      Window type:
          Dock
      Window state:
          Sticky
          Skip Pager
          Skip Taskbar
          Focused
      Process id: 2661 on host <redacted>
      Frame extents: 0, 0, 0, 0

  Normal window size hints:
      Program supplied minimum size: 1280 by 51
      Program supplied maximum size: 1280 by 51
      Program supplied base size: 0 by 0
      Program supplied window gravity: StaticGravity
  No zoom window size hints defined

  No window shape defined
  No border shape defined
```

Here are some screenshots to illustrate how it behaves as I change display settings. It's not really visible in the thumbnails; click on them to see the full-size versions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `xwininfo -d :0 -all`, you may get some hint on what process is displaying this. If you cannot type this in a graphic terminal when the problem occurs, you can switch to a regular console with Ctrl-Alt-Fn, type this, go back to your graphic session and click on the ghost window, and then go back to the console to read the output.

Comment: @xhienne `xwininfo` says it's `xfce4-panel`; I've put the full output in my question. Should I try sending it some signal with `kill`?

Comment: The PID of the faulty process is given (2661). Is it the PID of the `xfce4-panel` or of one of its sub-process? (`ps auxf` may be handy) You can kill 2661, if `xfce4-panel` dies, it may automatically respawn, though, I don't know. Save your work.

Comment: `ps` says PID 2661 is the only `xfce4-panel` command, with its parent being `xfce4-session`. Using `xwininfo` on the top panel gives the same PID but different window information. I'll try killing PID 2661 and let you what happens.

Comment: `kill 2661` got rid of the ghost window, as well as top and bottom panels. `xfce4-panel &` restored the panels but not the ghost window. Problem solved, I think! Thanks @xhienne for telling me about `xwininfo`!

Answer (score 1):

Easier solution: `xkill -frame` (try `xkill` first?)

1. Run `xwininfo -d :0 -all` (thanks [@xhienne](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/203203/xhienne)!) and click on the ghost window. Record the string in quotes after `Window id:` and the number after `Process id:`.
2. Run `kill`  followed by the number after `Process id:`.
3. If something unwanted disappears, restore it by running a command consisting of the string in quotes after `Window id:` followed by `&`.

Comment: If killing the faulty app was the only solution, then `xkill` would have been enough and quicker. I suggested `xwininfo` in order to get some hints about what was going wrong.

Comment: @xhienne Yeah, good point, it looks like that would've worked too, and been much easier: I tried doing `xkill` on one of the panels, and it closed both, but then restarted them. Feel free to post that as an answer, and I'll give it my upvote and the checkmark.

Comment: I'm glad you took the time to write an answer, you can checkmark your own. Moreover, I don't consider a kill as a definitive solution: your XFCE4 panel is obviously buggy, that bug can reappear at any time.

Comment: @xhienne It happened again. `xkill` didn't work, but `xkill -frame` did. I'm still not quite sure what the cause is. In this case, I noticed it after killing and restarting Firefox because it was overloading my computer, but I'm not sure when it first appeared.

Comment: I was not stating that `xkill` was easier than `xkill -frame`, but easier than the method based on `xwininfo` that I suggested in comment to your question (`xkill` just automates that manual process). This looks like a bug in `xfce4-panel` that you should report to the XFCE development team.